# Independence and Events.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let A, B and C are independent events. How am I supposed to prove that:

1. A′, B′ and C′ are independent.
2. A, B′ and C′ , are independent.
3. A, B and C' are independend.

This is my approach:

for Nr 3.

$P(ABC') = P(A)P(B)P(C').$
But $P(AB)=P(ABC)+P(ABC')$ and using independence 
$P(A)P(B) = P(A)P(B)P(C)+ P(ABC')$, 
therefore $P(A)P(B)(1-P(C))=P(ABC')$, 
$P(ABC') = P(A)P(B)P(C')$.

for Nr 2.

$P(AB'C') = P(A)P(B')P(C')$.
But $P(AC')=P(ABC')+P(ABC')$ and using independence 
$P(A)P(C') = P(A)P(B)P(C')+ P(A B' C')$, 
therefore $P(A)P(C')(1-P(B))=P(AB' C')$, 
$P(AB'C') = P(A)P(B')P(C')$.

And for Nr 1.

$P(A'B'C') = P(A')P(B')P(C')$.
But $P(A'B')=P(A'B' C )+P(A'B'C')$ and using independence 
$P(A')P(B') = P(A')P(B')P(C)+ P(A'B'C')$, 
therefore $P(A')P(B')(1-P(C))=P(A'B'C')$, 
$P(ABC') = P(A')P(B')P(C')$.

What do you think people? is this way of proving right?

Comment: Read the definition of independence carefully and look through [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101668/independence-of-events-verification/101672#101672) answer!

Comment: Hmmm, i see ! Thanks for your answer. what troubles me is that there are 3 events and not 2 like the most cases! Well i ll look into it now! thanks

Comment: Hint: Try to prove first that $A$, $B$ and $C'$ are inpedendent, than 2. and finally 1 (using what you've done in step one).

Comment: Hey martini!! thanks thanks!

Comment: For three events, one must show $P(A, B, C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$, and that the same factorization holds if you drop any of $A, B$ or $C$ from the above, e.g. $P(A, C) = P(A)P(C)$. Basically you have to get the factorization to hold for any subset of $\{A, B, C\}$.

Comment: Do i have to show that they are pairwise independent before i try anything else ?

Comment: Oh, could i follow this example here ? http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080221154925AAMIcxE , it looks quite good and i sort of understand, any1 to confirm ?

Comment: >Do i have to show that they are pairwise independent before i try anything else ?  You don't _have_ to prove pairwise independence since events that are mutually independent are also pairwise independent (the converse is not true). But contemplation of $$\begin{align*}P(A\cap B\cap C)&=P(A)P(B)P(C),\\P(A\cap B)&= P(A)P(B),\end{align*}$$ possibly subtracting one equation from the other, and figuring out whether $A\cap B\cap C$ and $A\cap B\cap C^\prime$ are a partition of $A\cap B$ or not might help.

Comment: Alright pals, I'll show that P(ABC') = P(A)P(B)P(C').
But P(AB)=P(ABC)+P(ABC') and using independence 
P(A)P(B) = P(A)P(B)P(C)+ P(ABC'), therefore
P(A)P(B)(1-P(C))=P(ABC'), and   (I Dont Understand this part At All)
P(ABC') = P(A)P(B)P(C').

Comment: Looks right. Do you see you did three times the same. You can use 3) in 2) for example as follows: If $A$, $B$, $C$ are independent, then by 3) $A$, $B$ and $C'$ are. Now $A$, $C'$ and $B$ are independent and therefore, by 3) applied for these events, $A$, $C'$ and $B'$ are.

Comment: I've merged the previous incarnation of the question with this one.

Comment: I have finally sovled it !! Thanks all for your help, i figured out! You may close this thread ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have shown this, but for clarity, using independence you have 
$$\Pr(ABC)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)$$ 
and 
$$\Pr(AB)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$$ 
so 
$$\Pr(ABC')=\Pr(AB)-\Pr(ABC) $$ $$=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)- \Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C) $$ $$= \Pr(A)\Pr(B)(1-\Pr(C))  $$ $$=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C')$$

so $A$, $B$ and $C'$ are independent events.

Since this is all commutative, as martini says, you can then derive (2) and (1).

Comment: ^ Very nice! actually it makes much more sense to me now, clarity, thats exactly what i needed! Thanks!

Comment: But i still can understand this -->  WHY Pr(A)Pr(B)−Pr(A)Pr(B)Pr(C)
=Pr(A)Pr(B)(1−Pr(C))   ?

Comment: @Adrian: In general $x\times y - x\times y \times z = x\times y \times (1-z)$ because of the common factor of $x \times y$

Comment: Actually, depending on what one assumes, proving that $\Pr(ABC^\prime)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C^\prime)$ is not quite sufficient to prove that $A$, $B$, $C^\prime$ are independent.  It is also necessary to assert (or remind the reader) that the other conditons $\Pr(AB)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$, $\Pr(AC^\prime)=\Pr(A)\Pr(C^\prime)$, $\Pr(BC^\prime)=\Pr(B)\Pr(C^\prime)$ follow from the results on pairwise independence of $A, B, C$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer/proof is **incomplete**.  In order to assert that three events $D$, $E$, $F$ are mutually independent, you have to verify that four equations hold:
$$\begin{align*}
P(DEF) &= P(D)P(E)P(F)\\
P(DE)  &= P(D)P(E)\\
P(DF)  &= P(D)P(F)\\
P(EF)  &= P(E)P(F)\\
\end{align*}$$
Taking $D=A$, $E=B$, $F=C^\prime$, you have verified the first of the four equations above. Now you need to say that $P(AB)=P(A)P(B)$ follows from the independence 
of $A$ and $B$,
and either *prove* that $P(AC^\prime) = P(A)P(C^\prime)$ and 
$P(BC^\prime) = P(B)P(C^\prime)$,
or assert that these follow from the independence of $A$ and $C$, and $B$ and $C$ respectively if you have done these kinds of calculations previously.

Another definition of independence of $n$ events $A_i$ is that all $2^n$ equations
$$P(A_1^*A_2^*\cdots A_n^*) = P(A_1^*)P(A_2^*)\cdots P(A_n^*)$$
must hold, where each $A_i^*$ stands for either $A_i$ or $A_i^\prime$, the same 
on both sides of the equation.  With this definition, the statements to be
proved in the OP's problem are true by definition and there is nothing to prove.

Comment: ^ quite enlightening post there, this is what i missed, finally , thanks, it seems that i totally forgot pairwise independence. Thats why, i had a weird feeling that my proof was just not right... Thanks!